# Using VBA code to all files in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract, from the ID column, the Telephone using:

```
Sub Left_Funcion()
Dim LResult As String
LResult = "=Left(B2,11)"

With Sheets("Worksheet")
    .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = LResult
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

I can do it with one file, but what to do when I want to do this to multiple files in folder like C:\Users\kowal\Documents\TestResults

what code i must add to makro?

Comment: i dont understand? why use this

Comment: refer: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_filesystem.asp

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all files in a directory using the Windows Scripting Host FileSystemObject:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SubForAllXlsFiles()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook


Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = "f:\temp\xls\"

For Each objFile In FSO.GetFolder(strPath).Files

  If InStr(objFile.Name, ".xls") Then

    Call Workbooks.Open(objFile)
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    With wb.Worksheets("Worksheet")
      .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = LResult
    End With

    Call wb.Save
    Call wb.Close
    Set wb = Nothing

  End If

Next objFile

End Sub
```

Comment: In which line do the error occur? Anyway, you have to conclude the variable `strPath`  with an \ - `strpath = "c:\users\kowal\documents\testresults\"`

Comment: that highlight yellow Private Sub SubForAllXlsFiles() and show error variable is not defined

Comment: Did you add new code? This code has no compilation errors because of non declared variables.

Comment: What is Call Workbooks.Open(...)? Do you mean workbooks.open ? Why do you have the Call ?

Comment: @ShaiRado You can use `Call` or omit it. It does the same.

Comment: Why use it, it's very 80's. why not Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...) ?

Comment: Habit I guess. Here it has no effect on the problem.